# Are Facebook Realtime API v2.3 improvements only for Pages or also Users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> Real-time Updates - As of March 25, 2015 We now send content in Page real-time updates (RTUs). Previously, only the object's ID was in the RTU payload. Now we include content in addition to the ID including: statuses, posts, shares, photos, videos, milestones, likes and comments. In order for the app to receive these types of updates, you must have enabled the "Realtime Updates v2.0 Behavior" migration in your app's dashboard. 
>   ([quote link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog))

I'm trying to use those APIs but for Users, not Pages, and what I'm getting in the POST callback is still just few information that tells me what changed but does not include the changes.

e.g.:

```
{"object":"user","entry":[{"uid":"1287361892736","id":"12983761897236","time":1827368128,"changed_fields":["feed"]}]}
```

Should I assume that Realtime APIs for Users was not updated and so I still need to call the REST APIs to get the new content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it myself in the description of the composition of the POST updates:

> changes: An array of the actual changes which triggered this update.
>   **This is only returned for page subscriptions**, in place of
>   changed_fields.

([link here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3))